# Definition of Infinite Dimensional Vector Space :

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In the text i am referring for Linear Algebra , following definition for Infinite dimensional vector space is given .

```
The Vector Space V(F) is said to be infinite dimensional vector space or

infinitely generated if there exists an infinite subset S of V such that L(S) = V.
```

I am having following questions which the definition fails to answer :-

1. Let us say i have an infinite dimensional vector space I(F) .If S is
   the infinite subset that spans  I(F) , can i say that S is Linearly
   Independent . If so , why ?
2. Does that mean any subset that
   spans every infinite dimensional vector space is Linearly
   Independent.
3. On similar lines , can i say that Basis will exist for each Infinite
   Dimensional Vector Space and it is nothing but the subset that spans
   over vector space ?

Comment: What's $L(S){}$?

Comment: L(S) is Linear Combination of S over the field F. Here , S is a subset of V. Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: "*If $S$ is* **the** *infinite subset that spans...*"  The article `the` carries some connotation in English that you think it is the only possible object that fits that description.  Vector spaces in general can have *many* different spanning sets.  You should have used the article `a` or `an` here instead implying you are aware that there could be others.  Now... a spanning set does not need to be linearly independent.  A *basis* does.  Don't confuse these.  As for your supposed definition you quoted, it is missing the condition that $S$ be linearly independent.

Comment: Consider... $\Bbb R^2$ is equal to the span of the vectors $\{(0,1),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),\dots\}$ yet $\Bbb R^2$ is 2-dimensional despite there being infinitely many vectors in the set used for the spanning set.  It just so happened that this choice of spanning set was *incredibly redundant* and not formed using linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Can we say any infinite dimensional vector space set will have a basis (whether finite or infinite ) for sure ?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Proof_that_every_vector_space_has_a_basis).

Comment: An infinite dimensional vector space will *never* have a finite basis.  An infinite dimensional vector space always having an infinite basis might or might not be true depending on whether you accept or reject the axiom of choice respectively.  Moving from the finite case to the infinite case, there are different competing notions for bases.  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Analysis).  In particular you have Hamel bases, Schauder bases, Markushevic bases, etc... with their different nuances.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $L(S)$ denotes the linear hull (or span) of $S$, which is the set of all linear combinations that can be formed from finitely many elements in $S$, the statement you gave is wrong:

Note that $V=\mathbb R^n$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, yet for the infinite set $S=\mathbb R^n$, we have $L(S)=V$.

The correct definition is that $V$ is infinite dimensional if there exists no finite $S$ such that $L(S)=V$. Or equivalently (by the axiom of choice) if there exists an infinite set $S$ that is **linearly independent** and satisfies $L(S)=V$. That is, $V$ is infinite dimensional if it admits no finite basis, which is equivalent to admitting an infinite basis.

Comment: How does V having no finite basis is equivalent to an infinite basis unless the linear independence of that infinite set is proved ?

Comment: A basis is a linearly independent spanning set by definition. [Every vector space admits a basis by the axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Proof_that_every_vector_space_has_a_basis), so if there is no finite basis, there has to be an infinite one.

Comment: Let W = {0} be subset of vector space V(F) ,where 0 is the identity element. Clearly W is a subspace of V(F). What is the basis of W?

Comment: $W=\{0\}$ is a $0$-dimensional subspace and accordingly there's only one basis of $W$: the empty set $\varnothing$.